# Is there a way to automatically format/delete my SSD after x failed login attempts?

Tags: macos, security, login, high-sierra, disk-format

On iOS there is the option to have the device delete all data after 10 failed login attempts. How can I have the same option on macOS so that my SSD gets deleted/reformated after x failed attemps to log into my user account?

Answer (score 6):

With on-board tools (and without using external services like "Find my Mac" & "Erase my Mac remotely" via iCloud) it's impossible to erase or reformat the boot volume with `diskutil ...` because the disk is *busy*.

---

You can remove your user folder though:

The method below uses a password policy and depending on the state of the user login capabilities, a launch daemon and a bash script invoked by the daemon will remove the user folder.

1. Create a password policy plist on your desktop:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>policyCategoryAuthentication</key>
       <array>
           <dict>
               <key>policyContent</key>
               <string>(policyAttributeFailedAuthentications &lt; policyAttributeMaximumFailedAuthentications) or (policyAttributeCurrentTime &gt; policyAttributeLastFailedAuthenticationTime + autoEnableInSeconds)</string>
               <key>policyIdentifier</key>
               <string>com.apple.maximumFailedLoginAttempts</string>
               <key>policyParameters</key>
               <dict>
                   <key>autoEnableInSeconds</key>
                   <integer>31536000</integer>
                   <key>policyAttributeMaximumFailedAuthentications</key>
                   <integer>10</integer>
               </dict>
           </dict>
       </array>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```

   The user login capabilities will be disabled after 10 failed login attempts for 31536000 seconds (=one year).
2. Create a bash script *rmuserdir.sh*:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   PWPOL=$(pwpolicy -u username authentication-allowed)

   if [[ $PWPOL == 'User <username> is not allowed to authenticate: Failed global policy "com.apple.maximumFailedLoginAttempts"'  ]]

   then rm -fR /Users/username

   fi
   ```

   in /usr/local/bin/ and make it executable. Replace the string *username* with your user's name but keep the angle brackets in the if statement!
3. Create a launch daemon *org.userdirrm.plist* in /Library/LaunchDaemons/ with the content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>Label</key>
       <string>org.userdirrm</string>
       <key>ProgramArguments</key>
       <array>
           <string>/bin/bash</string>
           <string>/usr/local/bin/rmuserdir.sh</string>
       </array>
       <key>RunAtLoad</key>
       <true/>
       <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
       <string>/tmp/org.userdirrm.stderr</string>
       <key>StandardOutPath</key>
       <string>/tmp/org.userdirrm.stdout</string>
       <key>StartInterval</key>
       <integer>60</integer>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```

   File owner and group has to be root:wheel and file permissions have to be 644. The daemon will run every 60 seconds. You can tweak this by changing the integer in the key *StartInterval*.
4. Import the password policy:

   ```
   pwpolicy setaccountpolicies ~/Desktop/pwpolicy.plist
   ```

   You have to enter your (authenticator=admin) password.
5. Launch the daemon:

   ```
   sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.userdirrm.plist
   ```

You can test the set-up by creating a stub user, changing the username in the bash script temporarily and entering wrong passwords trying to login with this stub user. You can lower the number of failed login attempts to 3 in the password policy temporarily to shorten the test.

Tweaks:

- adding the (rm) -P option in the shell script:

  > Overwrite regular files before deleting them.  Files are overwritten three times, first with the byte pattern 0xff, then 0x00, and then 0xff again, before they are deleted.
- trying to remove the root folder instead of your user folder:

  ```
  rm -fR /
  ```

  or

  ```
  rm -fRP /
  ```

  SIP protected files won't be removed/overwritten! To remove/delete/overwrite them also, you have to disable SIP.
- try to get the binary *srm* from an older OS X install, add it to High Sierra and use it in the bash script instead of *rm*. The binary *srm* securely removes files or directories. Check `man srm` for further options (I haven't tested this).

---

In my opinion the method outlined above can be circumvented by booting to Single User Mode, launching the opendirectoryd with launchctl (after the obligatory file system check and mounting the boot volume to /) and removing all password policies with `pwpolicy -clearaccountpolicies`.

**Therefore formatting or erasing disks or folders to "gain security" isn't recommended. Instead encrypt your main volume with FileVault2 and use good passwords for all users.**

Comment: 10 failed login attempts in total? Could it be ten times in a row?

Comment: @AndreAraujo Just test it with a stub user ;-)

Comment: I just did! It works very well! Thanks!

Comment: @AndreAraujo If you have a very short passwort and entering it & hitting the return key takes one second, you may have to wait up to 50 seconds until the user folder is deleted. The *rmuserdir.sh* runs every 60 seconds only...and 60 sec - 10 x 1 sec = 50 sec.

Comment: I tested many cases with a stub user, now I turn on for my user. But I changed some configs, job in 600 seconds (10 minutes) and autoEnableInSeconds with 84600 seconds. So, if my daughter or my wife tried something by mistake a have some time to act!

Comment: We (or I) may add some warning before removing your user folder. Even an iMessage to your iPhone shoud be possible meanwhile. On the other hand: if you have young daughter or son (or a cat!) hitting arbitrary keys on your keyboard, 10 password attempts are eaten up really fast.

Comment: Have you any idea, how to do? This warning be effective without being a potential alarming? Here in Brazil, we are living dark times, surveillance, and polices abuses. My FileVault is enabled, but an additional layer cloud be nice.

Comment: If FileVault2 is enabled the whole thing only works if the disk is unlocked (a user is/was logged in and the Mac wasn't shut down). Shutting down your Mac consequently before leaving it alone (or with young girls/boys/cats) is safe - and you won't lose any data (except when it gets confiscated - then you lose the whole Mac with all your data).

Comment: Yes, but supposing that my disk is unlocked could be a problem. Despite all, I have a backup for essential things.